# missing Layers in CloudRig property in animation

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image: You can see Layers panel is missing all info about layers of the rig I don't know why it's happening there should be layers info for hands, foot etc. as it is an officially made rig by blender, does anyone know why it's happening I am using 4.0 blender version]
You can see Layers panel is missing all info about layers of the rig I don't know why it's happening there should be layers info for hands, foot etc. as it is an officially made rig by blender, does anyone know why it's happening I am using 4.0 blender version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bone Layers have been removed from Blender 4.0 and replaced with Bone Collections. The draw function in rig_ui.py script is trying to draw buttons for layers which no longer exist in 4.0, so it fails to render those buttons. However, those layers should show fine in 3.6 and earlier.

[Pierrick Picaut made a video explaining how to fix this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiN3ZKlxZaI) **FOR RIGIFY** by adjusting rig_ui.py script so it works with 4.0. The downside of it is that it simply replaces Bone Layers with Bone Collections in the draw() function, so you will now have missing layers if you try to run the rig in 3.6.

What I do in addition to that is a simple version check within the draw() function so the appropriate commands are run for 3.6 and 4.0+, allowing any affected rig to display layers in both 3.6 and 4.0 (or rather, Bone Layers in 3.6 and Bone Collections in 4.0):

```
def draw(self, context):
    if (4,0,0) > bpy.app.version: #The existing code for 3.6. Nothing to edit here
        
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=0, toggle=True, text='Example layer') #Note the index number...
        
        #Whatever code for layers you have here...

    else: #code for 4.0+

        collection = bpy.data.armatures["rig"].collections #note you have to specify the name of your armature object

        row.prop(collection["Layer 1"],'is_visible',toggle=True,text='Example layer') #Note the collection name

        #You have to adjust the rest of the code the same way as above
```

As visible in the comments, the name of the corresponding Bone Collection is always "Layer " and an incremented number of the Bone Layer index.
E.g. I have the following code for a layer with index = 5:

```
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=5, toggle=True, text='Leg.L (FK)')
```

Because the index = 5, it will appear in 4.0 in the Bone Collection list as "Layer 6", so the code for 4.0 will look as following:

```
        row.prop(collection["Layer 6"],'is_visible',toggle=True,text='Leg.L (FK)')
```

Now as you've mentioned, you're using CloudRig rather than Rigify, but I think you should be able to find a similar function responsible for drawing the UI in there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The layers were moved to the object data properties on sidepanel]
well The layers of rig are moved to the other section and they now called "Bone Collection" I guess they should remove the Layers properties panel on CloudRig.